# Can I fail back from Node2 to Node1 when my SQL Server database is in recovery?

Tags: sql-server, clustering, failover

I recently failed over my SQL Server instance from Node1 to Node2 and noticed below informational message:

> Recovery of database 'huge_database' (22) is 24% complete (approximately 399 seconds remain). Phase 2 of 3. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

However, when checking from SSMS, I can see that the database is online. I haven't checked the "status" column from the sys.databases DMV. In this state, I am unsure whether I can fail back from Node2 to Node1 without causing any errors. Can anyone offer any insights or advice?

Answer (score 3):

> However, when checking from SSMS, I can see that the database is online. I haven't checked the "status" column from the sys.databases DMV.

Since the database is in an AG you shouldn't go by whatever SSMS tells you in general and `sys.databases` is not a full picture of the database state. Ideally you'll want to use `sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states` to check.

> In this state, I am unsure whether I can fail back from Node2 to Node1 without causing any errors.

You didn't specify in the original post, so it's hard to say. If the database is in a good state, you can fail over (the database on the replica that is going to *become* primary). Things you don't want to do is to attempt to fail over in the middle of `reverting`/`initializing` or when the database is not in a `synchronized` state.